# getting '401' error everytime when I request tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Im working on a project where im downloading tweets from twitter and storing them into json file. the project used to run fine one month back but now its giving error'401' every time when i try to request some tweets, I have tried regenerating the api keys but its not helping.

```
#Importing tweepy classes.

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import twitter_credential
#Creating MyStreamListenerclass
class TweetStreamer():

def __init__(self):
        pass


def stream_tweets(self, fetched_tweets_filename, search_param):
    #Adding credentials, referencing twitter_credential file.
        myStreamListener= MyStreamListener(fetched_tweets_filename)
        auth=OAuthHandler(Consumer_Key,Consumer_Key_Secret)
        auth.set_access_token(Access_Token,Access_Token_Secret)
        stream=Stream(auth, myStreamListener)
#Function to search for a tweet having particular word. For example:  Donald trump.
        stream.filter(track=search_param)



class MyStreamListener(StreamListener):

def __init__(self, fetched_tweets_filename):
    self.fetched_tweets_filename = fetched_tweets_filename

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        print(data)
        with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, 'a') as tf:
            tf.write(data)
        return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
    return True


def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)



#Main method.

if __name__=="__main__" :
  names=input("Enter keyword to be searched:")
  search_param= [names]    
  fetched_tweets_filename= "Tweet.json"
  twitter_streamer = TweetStreamer()
  twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(fetched_tweets_filename, search_param)
```

Comment: What's the response body?

Comment: getting 401 in response

Comment: It's not the response. It's your script's output.

Comment: how can I get the scripts output?